# Why don't we have different file extensions for MySQL and PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, file-extension

I guess I have 2 questions.

Q1) Why don't we have different extensions for MySQL and PostgreSQL?

Q2) To what extent are expressions SQL expressions and what are MySQL expressions?

Q1) I'm comfortable with MySQL and right now learning PostgreSQL.
I found that there are quite a few expressions that are used in MySQL and not in PostgreSQL.
(e.g. AUTO_INCREMENT, double quotations for strings)
So, why do we only have just .sql as the extension for both?
I don't think MySQL files won't run on PostgreSQL.
Why not use different extensions?

Q2) Even though different, there are so many similarities between the two DBMS syntactically.
I'm guessing it's because the similar ones are SQL expressions, and others are specific for each DBMS.
So, what are SQL expressions, and what are MySQL, PostgreSQL expressions?
How do we differentiate them?
Or are the no "SQL expressions"? Is it just that MySQL and PostgreSQL are similar?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using different extensions

Comment: So are you saying that we can write .mysql and .psql and we can run both? So .sql is just a convention?

Comment: Out of curiosity: which "extension" are you asking for? A file extension? What keeps you from using **any** available extension?

Comment: I kinda mentioned above, but the extension that I was talking about was .sql.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL standard has a number of expressions as part of its definition.

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/sql-in-a/9780596155322/ch04s02.html

See here for how Postgres and MySQL comply

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/compatibility.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/features.html

So most SQL system will provide the standard expressions, however most systems also provide a number of extensions. The extensions are often useful but clearly won't work on other database systems, because they are not standard.

If you need portability stick to the standard expressions, if you want convenience and don't care about portability use what your DB supports.